# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'split'), and i want to do some tags options

Tags: node.js, split, tags, ejs

```
<div class="row no-margin video-title">
    <h6><i class="fas fa-book"></i> Tags</h6>
</div>
<div class="image">
    <ul class="list-unstyled mb-0">
        <% 
            Tags = video.Tags.split(",");
            Tags.forEach (function (tag) {
            tag = tag.trim(); %>

            <li>
                <a href="/tag_search/<%= tag %>"><%= tag %></a>
            </li>

        <% }) %>
    </ul>
</div>
```

and I receive this error:

```
TypeError:
E:\livestreaming\video_streaming\views\video-page\index.ejs:374
    372|             
    373| 
 >> 374|             <%- include("side-bar") %>
    375|             
    376|         </div>
    377|     </div>

E:\livestreaming\video_streaming\views\video-page\side-bar.ejs:39
    37|     <div class="image">
    38|         <ul class="list-unstyled mb-0">
 >> 39|             <% 
    40|                 Tags = video.Tags.split(",");
    41|                 Tags.forEach (function (tag) {
    42|                 tag = tag.trim(); %>

Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'split')
    at eval ("E:\\livestreaming\\video_streaming\\views\\video-page\\side-bar.ejs":47:35)
    at side-bar (E:\livestreaming\video_streaming\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:692:17)
    at include (E:\livestreaming\video_streaming\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:690:39)
    at eval ("E:\\livestreaming\\video_streaming\\views\\video-page\\index.ejs":101:17)
    at index (E:\livestreaming\video_streaming\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:692:17)
    at tryHandleCache (E:\livestreaming\video_streaming\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:272:36)
    at View.exports.renderFile [as engine] (E:\livestreaming\video_streaming\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:489:10)
    at View.render (E:\livestreaming\video_streaming\node_modules\express\lib\view.js:135:8)
    at tryRender (E:\livestreaming\video_streaming\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:640:10)
    at Function.render (E:\livestreaming\video_streaming\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:592:3)
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need to learn to read the error, Elon!

> Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'split')

It is clearly saying, a property named `split` is attempted to be accessed from an `undefined` value.

Now, all you have to do is, to check where you are using `split` in the part of the code that throws the error.

Then you will learn that, it is `Tags = video.Tags.split(",");` where, `split` is being used. That means, `Tags` property in `video` object is not defined.

Now, you simply need to ensure `Tags` is present in `video` object always & it must be a string.

Comment: Sure, I identified the error, it was an error declaring the "tag" thank you so much for your reply!

Answer (score 0):

This means that `video.Tags` stores an `undefined` value. Make sure to check if the `video.Tags` has a value before using the `split()` method. See code below:

```js
var video = undefined;

// Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'split')
video.split(',');
```

To check whether your string is `undefined` or not:

```js
const video = undefined;

if (typeof video === 'string') {
  const array = video.split(',');
  // Do something ...
} else {
  console.log('video is not a string');
}

// You could also use method chaining.
const r = video?.split(','); 
console.log(r);
```